# Get item with value from tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple that I fetched from a query, but I'm not experienced with Python so I don't know the right/best way to do this. Here is what the tuple looks like:[image]

Now I need something like `result.getItemWithKey('111.111.5.1')` that returns a single array object or comma separated string ( as it's more useful) like 'object1, 111.111.5.1'

Comment: Can't you use a dictionary instead of a tuple? It would be easier for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "array object". There are more than one array implementation in python. But it looks like you want some other date type entirely, such as `list` or `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for a particular tuple in the results list by iterating over the list and checking the value of the second item of each tuple (which is your key):

```
results = [('object%d' % i, '111.111.5.%d' % i) for i in range(1,8)]

key = '111.111.5.4'
result = None
for t in results:
    if t[1] == key:
        result = t

print result
```

Output:

```
('object4', '111.111.5.4')
```

This demonstrates accessing an item in a tuple with a zero-based index (1 in this case means the second element). Your code will be more readable if you unpack the tuples in the for loop:

```
for obj, value in results:
    if value == key:
        result = (obj, value)
```

Your results might be more generally useful if you convert them to a dictionary:

```
>>> results_dict = {v:k for k,v in results}
>>> print results_dict['111.111.5.6']
object6
>>> print results_dict['111.111.5.1']
object1
>>> print results_dict['blah']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'blah'
>>> print results_dict.get('111.111.5.5')
object5
>>> print results_dict.get('123456')
None
```

Using `dict.get()` is close to the syntax that you requested in your question.

Comment: I'm on it now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your result is a tuple of tuples, so you can access it using indexes like this:

```
>>> result[0]
('object1', '111.111.5.1')
>>> result[0][0]
'object1'
>>> result[0][1]
'111.111.5.1'
```

You can read more about tuples (and other data structures) in the Python [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

So your function could look like this:

```
def get_item(result, key):
    for obj, num in result:
        if num == key:
            return obj, num
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the input tuple into a dictionary and access the keys from that. Something like this (only tested in python 3, so you might have do some changes to run with python 2.7 )

```
from collections import defaultdict
mytuples = (('object1', '111.111.5.1'), 
            ('object2', '111.111.5.1'), 
            ('object3', '111.111.5.3'), 
            ('object4', '111.111.5.4'),)
mydict = defaultdict(list)
for name, key in mytuples:
    mydict[key].append(name)

for key, values in mydict.items():
    print(key, values)
```

output:

```
111.111.5.1 ['object1', 'object2']
111.111.5.3 ['object3']
111.111.5.4 ['object4']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to index into the tuple follow mentions answer. If you are wanting to search by a key

```
result.getItemWithKey('111.111.5.1')
```

then you may want to use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in place of the tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse elements of your tuple in dict comprehension:

```
test = ((1, 'R'), (2, 'K'))
values = {y: x for x, y in test}
values['R']
1
```